# What is the developer flow for ember-engines?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-engines

I am just beginning to look into Ember.js engines. One thing that stands out is that for every change I make in the engine code I need to re-install it into the host application. There is no live reload, rebuild or any of this.

Is there a way to smooth out this flow as it would slow down development considerably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to set `isDevelopingAddon` like so in the index.js file for the addon and use NPM link to get it into the main application `node_packages` folder - you will then get live reload, etc-:

```
// Addon index.js
isDevelopingAddon: function() {
  return true;
}
```

To add to this I found an interesting article here: *[Ember and Yarn Workspaces](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/ember-and-yarn-workspaces-fca69dc5d44a)*